# jQuery plugin to bind ctrl + mouseclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The [jquery.hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys) lets you easily add and remove handlers for keyboard events. However, this plugin can handle keyboard event only but not mouse click event. So it does not support something like:

```
$('#gallery li.icon').bind('click', 'ctrl+leftbutton', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I know this is not difficult to implement, but I am curious if someone has already posted a neat solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the event's [`.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey) property for this, for example:

```
$('#gallery li.icon').click(function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey) $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

In this we're just checking if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is down then the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event happened.  Just to be clear, `.ctrlKey` is basic JavaScript, there's no dependency on the hotkeys plugin.

Comment: Thanks! Actually the hotkeys plugin uses the similar technique. I ended up modifying the plugin a little bit to fit my need. `$('#foo').bind('click', 'ctrl+shift+rightbutton', fn)` is definitely cleaner than three `if` clauses.

Comment: @powerboy - true...but you're also including a plugin where 3 boolean checks (one `if` statement) will do the job :) for example: `if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.button == 2) $(this).addClass('selected');` vs an entire plugin :)  If you're doing it all over, sure...but a plugin is tremendous overkill for doing just this.